# How to save Meta box having many Tabs?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a plugin similar to Woocommerce with the only difference that it will only add products and no other functionality. I have build a meta box having 7 tabs. Which will be shown and hide as per the value selected from drop box. Now my problem is how i can save the whole meta box with each value of tabs? Here is my code of Meta box :

```
    `add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_product_fields_box');

    function add_product_fields_box() {
add_meta_box('product-data', 'Product Data', 'display_product_info_box', 'cproduct', 'normal');}

     function display_product_info_box() {
//echo "This is Meta Box 1";?> 
<div>
    <h2>Product Data ----
    <select id="producttype">
        <optgroup label="Product Type">
            <!--<option value="0"><b>Product Type</b></option>-->
            <option value="1" selected>Simple Product</option>
            <option value="2">Grouped Product</option>
            <option value="3">External/Affiliate Product</option>
            <option value="4">Variable Product</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
    <span>|</span>
    <span id="virtual">Virtual <input type="checkbox" id="virchk" name="virtual"></span>
    <span id="download">Downloadable <input type="checkbox" id="dowchk" name="download"></span>
    </h2>
</div>
<div id="acme-navigation">
    <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper current">
        <a id="tabgeneral" class="nav-tab nav-tab-active" href="#acme-general">General</a>
        <a id="tabinventory" class="nav-tab" href="#acme-inventory">Inventory</a>
        <a id="tabshipping" class="nav-tab" href="#acme-shipping">Shipping</a>
        <a id="tablinked" class="nav-tab" href="#acme-linked-products">Linked Products</a>
        <a id="tabattribute" class="nav-tab" href="#acme-attributes">Attributes</a>
        <a id="tabvariation" class="nav-tab" href="#acme-attributes">Variations</a>
        <a id="tabadvance" class="nav-tab" href="#acme-advanced">Advanced</a>
    </h2>
</div>

<?php include_once( 'partials/general.php' ); ?>
<?php include_once( 'partials/inventory.php' ); ?>
<?php include_once( 'partials/shipping.php' ); ?>
<?php include_once( 'partials/linked-products.php' ); ?>
<?php include_once( 'partials/attributes.php' ); ?>
<?php include_once( 'partials/variations.php' ); ?>
<?php include_once( 'partials/advanced.php' ); ?>

<div id="custom-meta-box-nonce" class="hidden">
    <?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'acme-custom-meta-box-nonce' ); ?>
</div>
<br/> <?php
//include('Data/Views/first.php');}`
```

Please help me to write save function as i dont know where to start from.

Comment: The publish button call the save method but if you have some tabs you should pre-save this data

Comment: you have to save it on add_action('save_post', 'kvkoolitus_prices_save_meta');

Comment: Thank you For the answer :) It was a great help